# How can I know if the an FDA news release was before, after or during NYSE hours?

Tags: united-states, trading, shares, nyse

The article I am referring to doesn't seem to display the exact date. I was wondering if there was some way to find out? I don't know very much in terms of the FDA and I am looking to get into trading pharmaceuticals.

https://www.fda.gov/newsevents/newsroom/pressannouncements/ucm607501.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FDA press release in your link has the date near the top of the page.  You could also obtain it by Googling "Gilenya Novartis".  My trading platform indicated that the news release was at 4:32 PM yesterday so it was in the after market (and NVS then rose 45 cents).

You can sign up for FDA (U.S. Food & Drug Administration) email updates.  I don't know if they post their announcements in a timely fashion on their web  site.  You're likely to pick them up a lot faster with real time news but you'd have to be aware which clinical trial verdicts and drug approvals were pending and that entails a bit of leg work to track them as well as access to real time news with symbol alerts.

Be aware that clincial trials and approval/denial verdicts can be binary events for smaller pharma/bio companies with small  product lines.  For larger ones like Novartis, much less so.  If you're going to trade after a news release, you're going to have to be very disciplined if it's during after hours since low liquidity enhances volatility and you can't afford to be the deer in the headlights.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Because Novartis already had a reaction in the after market. Does that mean it is less likely to have a reaction to the fda approval the  next time the stock market opens? I don't know much about pre-market and after market so thanks for pointing that out as well.

Comment: How can I get access to real time news? Just google? or is there some paid service. My broker doesn't offer news. I was considering switching to suretrader.

Comment: Googling "Gilenya novartis" led me to their article which also didn't post the exact time of day(only the day). Is the only way to reliably get the exact time the news is released in this case from a broker?

Comment: https://www.novartis.com/news/media-releases/novartis-announces-fda-approval-gilenyar-first-disease-modifying-therapy-pediatric-relapsing-multiple-sclerosis

Comment: Sorry for so many comments :D

Comment: AFAIC, you can make as many comments as you want. If you don't ask, how are you going to learn?  There's no way to know what NVS will do in the pre market Monday AM or when regular trading opens at 9:30 AM EST.  NVS ended up 90 cts in the after market on Friday.  90 cents implies that it's not a blockbuster drug nor is it expected to affect NVS earnings dramatically.  Implies does not mean fact. Watch NVS in the pre market Monday morning to see if after processed, the news is any more meaningful. Google: "NASDAQ extended trading" for pre and after market quotes.  Is delayed info not real time.

Comment: @ Mr Gibbous - The premier news service is Bloomberg but that costs an arm and a leg. Most large mainstream large brokers provide real time news.  15 years ago I had real time Dow Jones News at Datek for $39.95 per month (long since acquired).  Then I found that it was free at Scottrade if you parked $500 in an account but they have been acquired by TDAmeritrade.  The point?  Look around and you may find a deal. If you are aware of a pending news release, you can set a price alert (up and down) on your brokerage platform and if there's a price reaction to news, you'll be beeped.

Comment: One other thought - Another occasional source of pharma news is health care conferences. For example, Cowen and Company holds a large  one every year in March.

Comment: thanks for all the advice. You have helped me tremendously.